# Sublists in Python based on condition

Tags: python, sql, list, sublist

I would like to get sublist of a list having more than 300 000 lines.

```
line1 = [field1,field2,field3,code1]
```

Where code1 is a 5 character string

I would like to do something like a select statement in sql

```
select * from table where code1 = '78100'
```

I tried doing the below with itertools but i do not know how to use the grouperobject it returns.

```
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

with open(r"csvfile", "rU") as f:

    reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=';')
    sortedreader = sorted(reader, key=lambda d: (d['insee']))
    groups = groupby(sortedreader, key=lambda d: (d['insee']))
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done to solve the problem. Only then will we be able to help you out.

Comment: What you have done till now?

Comment: get the index of code 1 what is the problem in that?

Comment: or use line1[-1] to print code1

Comment: Why not read up on [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Comment: `[line for line in big_list if line[-1] == '78100']`

Comment: Thanks @PaulPanzer and Ev.Kounis

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
long_list = [[1, 2, 3, '12345'],
             [1, 2, 3, '78100']]

def filter_list(long_list, pos, value):
    filtered_list = []
    for line in long_list:
        if line[pos] == value:
            filtered_list += line
    return filtered_list


print(filter_list(long_list, 3, '78100'))
```

Comment: Thanks!Exactly but i do not want to iterate over the 300 000 lines everytime

Comment: What so you mean every time? How would you want to find out which lines are the ones you want if you do not iterate over the lines?

Comment: I am looking for a way to speed up the creation of this sublist because i will be creating it a few hundred times in my script.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here. i'd repost a new question. Cheers